# For loop to check values from two spreadsheets

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two spreadsheets:

- Column A on sheet 6th&7thRoster lists all IDs in a sample, contains 853 items.
- Column C on sheet alreadySubmitted contains the IDs of users who've completed a task. Contains 632 items.

I'm trying to parse through both columns. If a user from Column A of sheet 6th&7thRoster matches a user from Column C of sheet sandboxAlreadySubmitted, I want to write the word "Yes" on Column I of the current row of sheet 6th&7thRoster. When using the code below, I'm not seeing not seeing any instances of the word "Yes" on Column I of 6th&7thRoster, even though I know there's multiple places where that should be the case.

```
function checkRoster() {
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXX');
  var roster = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6th&7thRoster');
  var submissions = mainSheet.getSheetByName('alreadySubmitted');

  var rosterLastRow = roster.getLastRow();
  var submissionsLastRow = submissions.getLastRow();

  var rosterArray = roster.getRange('A2:A853').getValues();
  var submissionsArray = submissions.getRange('C2:C632').getValues;

  var i;
  var x;
  for (i = 1; i < 853; i++) {
    for (x = 1; x < 632; x++){
      if (rosterArray[i] == submissionsArray[x]){
        roster.getRange(i, 9).setValue("Yes");
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Feedback on how to solve and achieve this task will be much appreciated. For confidentiality, I cannot share the original sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to compate the values of `A2:A853` of `6th&7thRoster` and `C2:C632` of `alreadySubmitted`.
- When the values of `C2:C632` of `alreadySubmitted` are the same with the values of `A2:A853` of `6th&7thRoster`, you want to put `Yes` to the column "I".

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function checkRoster() {
  var mainSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXX');
  var roster = mainSheet.getSheetByName('6th&7thRoster');
  var submissions = mainSheet.getSheetByName('alreadySubmitted');

  var rosterLastRow = roster.getLastRow();
  var submissionsLastRow = submissions.getLastRow();

  var rosterArray = roster.getRange('A2:A853').getValues();
  var submissionsArray = submissions.getRange('C2:C632').getValues(); // Modified

  // I modified below script.
  var obj = submissionsArray.reduce(function(o, [v]) {
    if (v) o[v] = true;
    return o;
  }, {});
  var values = rosterArray.map(function([v]) {return [obj[v] ? "Yes" : ""]});
  roster.getRange(2, 9, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve values from `A2:A853` of `6th&7thRoster` and `C2:C632` of `alreadySubmitted`.
2. Create an object for searching the values from the values of `alreadySubmitted`.
3. Create the row values for putting to `6th&7thRoster`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.